# How to dynamically create a number of NSMutableArray(s)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

On `touch up inside` of SAVE button, the following code is executed:

```
- (IBAction)onSave:(id)sender {

    savecount++;
    [self saveNumberOfContacts];

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myArray addObject:nameTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:phoneTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:addressTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:cityTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:stateTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:zipcodeTextField.text];

    [myArray writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

This creates a single array. I want to know how to dynamically create multiple arrays with the `savecount` variable suffixed at end of the array name.

For example, if my `savecount` is 3, then myArray1, myArray2, myArray3 should be created.

P.S. `savecount` changes its value dynamically.

EDIT: i dont want this method creating a number of arrays every time i call it. See, the user's info is stored in `myArray1` when i click save for the first time. Now, the `savecount` gets increemented(say,savecount=2). When i enter another user's details and click save, i dont want `myArray1` to be overwritten or disturbed; the second user's details must be independently saved in `myArray2`.

Comment: simple you need  to use for loop and put your code inside it :)

Comment: Make 2D array that can solve you issue i think

Comment: @iPatel maybe i didnt make it clear, i dont want this method creating a number of arrays every time i call it. See, the user's info is stored in `myArray1` when i click save for the first time. Now, the `savecount` gets increemented(say,savecount=2). When i enter another user's details and click save, i dont want `myArray1` to be overwritten or disturbed; the second user's details must be independently saved in `myArray2`.

Comment: check out https://github.com/nicklockwood/BaseModel model class, which really helpful in managing data in plist.

Comment: @motox u got 3 answers below, r they not helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *holder;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    holder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
- (IBAction)onSave:(id)sender {

    savecount++;
    [self saveNumberOfContacts];

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myArray addObject:nameTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:phoneTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:addressTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:cityTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:stateTextField.text];
    [myArray addObject:zipcodeTextField.text];

    [myArray writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];

    [holder addObject:myArray];
}
```

Have one global array in which you can hold dynamically created array. Now when you get value from `holder`, you will have separated `myArray` object.

Comment: Check EDIT. Im confused if your answer would accomplish the task

Comment: You want to preserve value of user1 while saving user2's details, then you must need to save previous array to some data holder say array, dictionary etc. If you implement above code and if you want to access user1's detail, you can do it with [holder objectAtIndex:0] and access array elements from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using these arrays within one method, you could instead store the arrays in an array. This doesn't give you array names such as myArray1, myArray2, etc, but accomplishes the same overall task. Here's an example:

```
NSMutableArray *myArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:savecount];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < savecount; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [myArrays addObject:newArray];
    [newArray addObject:nameTextField.text];
    // continue adding your objects to newArray
}
```

Now you can reference your arrays as `[myArrays objectAtIndex:0]`...`[myArrays objectAtIndex:savecount-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the path of save, or same path with appended array data.

If save data to different path:

```
- (NSString*)saveFilePath{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d.%@", thePathToSave, fileName, savecount, fileType];
}
```

If save to same path with appended array data:

Replace:

```
[myArray writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

with

```
NSArray *fileData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self saveFilePath]];
NSMutableArray *preDatas = nil;
if (preDatas.count == 0) {
    preDatas = [NSMutableArray array];
}
else{
    preDatas = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fileData];
}
[preDatas addObject:myArray];
[preDatas writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
```